# Multiple sites by using only one code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

when a user open any link of our application i need a controller by name site_check or any else which does the following things, firstly get site url opened exactly like "www.google.com" , i need to store the data like only google.com and if this value is checked with the database if exist.
if exist give a go add a local cookie of the same. Don't need to check this again until session is removed. 
i will store the values like i need to pull the title logo and other static data from the platform to this.

how many possible ways are there we can try this to workout.

I am a new to this codeigniter and coding, needed your help.. how to start it I'm not getting any idea, please help me out.

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: I don't have any idea what to do, Where to start & how to start..

Comment: do you atleast have your CI set up and views rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is my solution and i have used it to develop single core multiple sites create a setting table save basic info like domain, site name and template information in that table add many setting later on, create MY_Controller under core directory check domain exist in your database or not

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $site_id = 0;
    public $template = '';

    function __construct(){
        parenet::__construct()
        $this->loadSetting();
    }

    function loadSetting(){
        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $row = $this->db->where_like('domain',$host)->get('setting')->row();
        $this->site_id = $row->id;
        $this->template = $row->template;
    }
}
```

Once you setting is done you can add site_id as foreign key in your other tables like pages, news to get site specific pages and news and other information about site. Now extend your Page Controller or News Controller with MY_Controller like this.

```
class Page_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
   }

   function index(){
      $page = $this->db->get_where('pages',array('site_id',$this->site_id))->row();
   }
}
```

if you further want site_id available every where in your application you can create a library and autoload that library and you can put loadSetting method in that library. Like

```
class Setting {
   private $ci;
   public $site_id;
   public $template;

   function __construct(){
      $this->ci = get_instance();
      $this->loadSetting();
   }  

function loadSetting(){
            $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $row = $this->ci->db->where_like('domain',$host)->get('setting')->row();
            $this->site_id = $row->id;
            $this->template = $row->template;
        }

}
```

Now you can access site_id in your application anywhere like models other libraries and controller like this

```
$this->setting->site_id;
```

hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks umefarooq one more thing when I want to check the db whether the site exist or not if he enters the link like google.com -> i am saving like this in db, if he enter's the link like www.google.com, then how to exclude the www from the entered to check in the db

Comment: don't worry about that you can check above code i am using like in sql where condition it will be like this where domain like "%google.com%" user enter either google.com or www.google.com will work, please up my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to create Access Control layer for users in your organization to access certain websites which you want to permit. Though in a network environment behind [NAT](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/N/NAT.html) Server a simple proxy server like Microsoft ISA or any third party like Kerio can help you out by creating a simple rule

But if you want to do the same in Codeigniter, you need to startup with the following

**Step-1**

Create a Database table for Permitted sites like

```
id | website        
----------------------------------
1  | facebook.com   
2  | youtube.com
```

You need to have users table like

```
id  | username       | details
-------------------------------------
1   | Mudassar       | php developer
```

You need to have a user-permission table like

```
id  | user_id   | site_id  | permission
----------------------------------------
1   |    1      |   2      | allowed
```

Now Login your user

```
public function Login()
{
  if($_POST)
  {
     // You can perform Validation here

     $user_data=$this->Login_Model->checkUser($_POST);
     if($user_data)
     {
        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
        redirect(base_url().'user/dashboard'); // or whatever link
     }
  }
  else
  {
       $this->load->view('login_view');
  }
}
```

So now you have user_id in your session. Time to load your dashboard which supposedly have link to different websites

```
public function dashboard()
{
    $data['sites']=$this->User_Model->getPermittedSites();
    // Now you are only sending permitted sites to the user view
    $this->load->view('dashboard',$data);
}
```

If you want to make things complicated, there are tons of ways but this is simplest.